# concatenate or "xor" keys before hash to create unique id?

Tags: security, hash, sha1, xor

I want to create a unique id for a device, so I have decided to create SHA1(mac XOR timestamp XOR user_password). Is there any security problem related with this? Would it be better to do SHA1(mac CONCATENATE timestamp CONCATENATE user_password)?

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

Use concatenation - then you'll be basing your hash on *all* of the available source data.

If you use XOR then there's a risk that one piece of your source data will "cancel out" some (or all) of the bits of the remaining data before it's even passed to the hash function.

And concatenating rather than XORing won't affect the space required for storage of your hash - the generated SHA1 hash will always be 20 bytes regardless of the size of your source data.

Comment: Thank you, ok, I assume that is "more" risky, but just a very little more risk, cause even in case one piece cancell out data of other pieces, the sha1 will apparently generate a strong hash, am I wrong?

Comment: @user529361: The issue isn't really the strength of the hash, rather the "uniqueness" of your source data. For example, `SHA1(1^2^3)` == `SHA1(1^3^2)` == `SHA1(2^1^3)` == `SHA1(2^3^1)` == `SHA1(3^1^2)` == `SHA1(3^2^1)`, whereas `SHA1(123)` != `SHA1(132)` != `SHA1(213)` != `SHA1(231)` != `SHA1(312)` != `SHA1(321)` etc etc.